# How to group messages by date with vue.js? [Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to group message by date like in facebook messenger. I'm getting error 
**[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function**

Here is [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/h71svuLr/3/) for simple code.

```js
var app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
        data: {
            messages: [
                {
                    content: "Hello",
                    position: "left",
                    created_at: 1551437421000
                },
                {
                    content: "Hi",
                    position: "right",
                    created_at: 1551437421000
                },
                {
                    content: "How are you",
                    position: "left",
                    created_at: 1551523821000
                },
                {
                    content: "I'm fine",
                    position: "right",
                    created_at: 1551610221000
                },
                {
                    content: "Nice to meet you!",
                    position: "right",
                    created_at: 1551610221000
                },
                {
                  content: "How's going?",
                    position: "left",
                    created_at: 1551869421000,
                },
                 {
                    content: "Fine",
                    position: "right",
                    created_at: 1551869421000
                },
            ],
            temp: {
                old_unique_date: null
            }
        }, 
        methods: {          
         groupByDate(date){
           var old_date = this.temp.old_unique_date;
            var new_date = new Date(date).getDate();
            if(old_date != new_date){
              this.temp.old_unique_date = new_date;
              var day =  ("0" + new Date(date).getDate()).slice(-2);
              var month =  ("0" + (new Date(date).getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
              var date_data = day +"/"+ month;
              return date_data;
            }else{
              return "";
            }
         }
      }
      })
```

```css
.message {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  max-width: 60%;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.chat_room {
  position: relative;
}

.date {
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}

.c_f {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="chat_room">
    <div v-for="message in messages">
      <div class="date" v-html="groupByDate(message.created_at)">
      </div>
      <div class="message" :class="message.position">
        {{message.content}}
      </div>
      <div class="c_f"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You can see the red date.
created_at are date of message sent. When a message is sent at 01/03, then I would like to show only one 01/03 for all messages which sent date is 01/03. It seen ok in view. But it's has console error called "[Vue warn]: You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function."

Comment: Is it possible for you to create jsFiddle for your problem. I tried your HTML and JS, It worked fine for me.

Comment: Right now it's not clear what your `groupByDate` is supposed to do. One thing is sure: it doesn't ***group*** anything, at least not in the sense most people understand grouping. I made a [small example](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/hzywastj/) to help you visualize its output.

Comment: Here is jsFiddle.  https://jsfiddle.net/1d8xn0vr/

Comment: You can see red date. I would like to show one for same date. For example if you the message is sent at 01/03 and another message is also sent at 01/03. Then I would like to show only one 01/03 for once.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uxwv9q2m/ But of course is better to group messages before rendering in the Group<date, message[]>